# Weird error when trying to compare numbers

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the next piece of code -

```
def findBestHypothesis():

    bestOfBest = []
    currentERMValue = 0
    bestERMValue = 0

    for polynom in bestOfHypothesisClasses:
        for j in range(0, len(training_set)):
            currentERMValue += (np.polyval(polynom, training_set[x_value_index]) -
                                training_set[y_value_index])**2

        if currentERMValue >= bestERMValue:
            bestERMValue = currentERMValue
            currentERMValue = 0
            bestOfBest = polynom

    return bestOfBest
```

As you can see, currentERMValue and bestERMValue are numbers and not arrays. But yet i get this -

> if np.greater_equal(currentERMValue, bestERMValue): ValueError: The
>   truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use
>   a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Why aren't you using `j` anywhere in the inner `for` loop?

Comment: If you add a `print(type(currentERMValue))` just before the `>=` comparison, what does the output look like?

Comment: @MarkDickinson <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`polyval` on an array returns an array, one element for each `x` value:

```
>>> np.polyval([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
array([27, 38, 51])
```

so either training_set is a two dimensional array, or x_value_index or y_value_index are not scalars.

Comment: I suspect that `training_set` is a 2d array, and that the OP wants `training_set[j, x_value_index]` rather than `training_set[x_value_index]` (and similarly for `y_value_index`).

Comment: training_set is an array of 2-tuples and i want to evalute the polynom in training_set[x_value_index], which is a scalar

Comment: @AlexGoft: If `training_set` is an array of 2-tuples, wouldn't `training_set[some_index]` be a 2-tuple? I don't see how you get a scalar out of that.

Comment: still the same error after i fix it to `training_set[j][x_value_index]`

Comment: @AlexGoft: Did you also add a `j` for the `y_value_index` part of the expression?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but np.polyval return several values.

Returns:
values : ndarray or poly1d
If x is a poly1d instance, the result is the composition of the two polynomials, i.e., x is “substituted” in p and the simplified result is returned. In addition, the type of x - array_like or poly1d - governs the type of the output: x array_like => values array_like, x a poly1d object => values is also.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html